# C++ with GLUT static compile on linux

Tags: c++, linux, g++, glut

I am trying to compile simple program to standalone executable so i can send it to my friend. But i am facing a problem with GLUT dependencies. Command i tried is:

```
g++ triangle.cpp -static -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm
```

And i got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When i try to use Mingw64 i get this:

```
    i686-w64-mingw32-g++ triangle.cpp -static -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm -o test.exe

    triangle.cpp:9:21: fatal error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GL/glut.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

My includes

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: You have to tell the compiler where to find header files (usually a `-I` option) and the linker where to find libraries (usually a `-L` option).

Comment: Could you pls tell me exactly how do i do it?

Comment: Read the documentation for your compiler. Start by looking up the two options I've mentioned.

Comment: a did this: `g++ triangle.cpp -static -L /usr/include/GL/glut.h -L /usr/include/GL/glu.h  -lm -L /usr/include/GL/gl.h` and i gave me a lot of undefined reference errors. For example `triangle.cpp:(.text+0x79b): undefined reference to `glClear'`

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that you do not have the GLUT libraries installed.
For GNU linux with aptitude, try

```
apt-get update
apt-cache search freeglut
```

to get a list of all libraries containing *freeglut*.
I **think** (not totally sure) that you need *freeglut3-dev* installed.